# I want to find thread message and delete it with slack-api

Tags: python, slack-api

Private messages or Direct messages can be found with methods such as `im.history` and `converstation.history`.

How to find thread message? I want to find thread messages and delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finding thread messages**

You need to use the [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) method to retrieve the parent message of a thread.

And then the [`conversations.replies`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.replies) method to retrieve the thread including all thread messages for a parent message.

You can detect a parent message by looking on the `ts` and `thread_ts` properties:

> When a message has a thread_ts value and it *matches* the same message's
>   ts, the message is a thread parent.

For more information check out the official documentation: [Finding message threads in the wild](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading#finding_message_threads_in_the_wild)

**Deleting thread messages**

You can delete a thread message the same way as with normal message using the [`chat.delete`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete) method.