# How to get a thread reply's content from reaction_added event?

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api, bolts-framework

I'm building a slack FAQ app that uses message reactions to gather the best answers to questions. My plan is to save any Slack messages with positive reactions by using the `reaction_added` event to get the TS attribute and then the `conversations.history` method to get the message's content.

This works well for parent-level or non-threaded messages, however it doesn't work for reply messages inside threads. For some reason the `conversations.history` method returns an unrelated message when using the TS  of a thread reply.

I've checked the Slack API `conversations.history` method documentation to see if replies are handled in any special way. I reviewed `conversations.replies` method to see if it might be helpful, but since `reaction_added` event simply provides a TS id for the message and no thread_ts value that can be used with the `conversations.replies` method.

I'm using bolt framework. Here's a snippet of the code that tries to use the `reaction_added` event with `conversations.history` method to get the message content:

```
app.event('reaction_added', async ({ event, context, say }) => {
  try {
    const result = await app.client.conversations.history({
      token: process.env.SLACK_USER_TOKEN,
      channel: event.item.channel,
      latest: event.item.ts,
      limit: 1,
      inclusive: true
    });
    save(`${result.messages[0].text}`);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Expected result:
Message contents of thread reply that a reaction is posted for

Actual result:
Message contents of the latest message in the slack channel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to find thread message and delete it with slack-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657092/i-want-to-find-thread-message-and-delete-it-with-slack-api)

Comment: The difference is this question is specifically asking for advice in finding a thread message when all you have a `reaction_added` event, which doesn't provide the required `thread_ts` attribute for finding a thread message.

Comment: You are right. Just repeated your example and the `reaction_added` event does not include the `thread_ts` property, which you would need to identify the related message in a thread. Looks like a missing feature to me, so I would suggest opening as support request to Slack about this.

Comment: Thanks, I did. I'll continue looking for workarounds too and post here if I find something.

Comment: I also contact Slack support about this. I think it would be trivial for them to add it so I hope they can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it changed recently or I misread the documentation, but `conversations.replies` API endpoint does not require a `thread_ts` value containing the parent thread timestamp in order to retrieve a thread reply.

The `event.item.ts` value provided by the `reaction_added` event is sufficient to retrieve the message contents of the reply where a reaction was added.

So to get the message contents of a message where a reaction was added, you can update the code in my original question to:

```
app.event('reaction_added', async ({ event, context, say }) => {
  try {
    const result = await app.client.conversations.replies({
      token: process.env.SLACK_USER_TOKEN,
      channel: event.item.channel,
      ts: event.item.ts
    });
    save(`${result.messages[0].text}`);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```